# Java, program to check which int is larger

Tags: java

I'm new in Java and have encountered a coding problem in a program which is ment to return which given integer is larger.

my code (EDIT);

```
   public class mandag25nov
{
    public static void main(Strings[] args)
    {
        max(a, b);
    }
    public static int max(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a > b)
        {
            return a;
        }
        else
        {
            return b;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, you can't nest functions like that. Also, that function is built-in (Math.max)

Comment: It is not possible to nest a method within a method.

Comment: This looks like homework. What happens, and what do you expect should happen with your code? And what does your error message tell you?

Comment: Too all the down voters. Give the guy/girl some slack. We've all had to begin somewhere so let someone make mistakes! Atleast we can learn from them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're putting your method inside the main method, effectively *nesting* it. This isn't allowed. Place your max method outside of the main method, and remove the static keyword from the class declaration.

```
public class mandag25nov
{
    public static void main(Strings[] args)
    {
        max(0, 1) //place the desired arguments in here
    }

    public static int max(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a > b)
        {
            return a;
        }
        else
        {
            return b;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can not have a method inside main method
Well as @kocko has pointed out,you **can not** also include one method inside another method

Comment: Not only inside the main method, but inside methods in general.

Comment: @kocko yes true,But as OP's post is inside main so thought of telling where he made mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can't have nested method(method inside another method) in Java. Move the `max()` method outside the `main()` method.

```
public static void main(Strings[] args)
{
    int maxNum = max(1,2); // call max method like this, example
}
public static int max(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can't use method inside methods.You have to use a separate function for that or you can use java built in functions.

```
int max = Math.max(a,b);
```

But you can always call a method from inside another method's body. Like below.

```
public static class mandag25nov
{
       public static void main(Strings[] args)
       {
           int maxNum =  max(10, 30);
       } 

       public static int max(int a, int b){

          if (a > b){            
            return a;
          }
          else{            
            return b;
          }
       }
}
```

Comment: well the main prob is nested method

Comment: While this is a preferred solution, it is not helpful for the OP.

Comment: yeah.. and he is saying  `Any help would be highly appreciated` :)

Comment: Yes, but the context of the question regards the OP's code as not working. One should assume that the OP wants an explanation on why it is not working and how it should be changed to get it working.

Comment: you are correct. :) then he may find a way to `how it should be changed to get it working` from my answer :)

Comment: @Troubleshoot : i edited it a little. thanks for your thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

Your program look like this

```
class mandag25nov
    {
    public int maxNumberIs(int a, int b)
            {
                if (a > b)
                {
                    return a;
                }
                else
                {
                    return b;
                }
            }
        public static void main(Strings[] args)
        {
            mandag25nov obj=new mandag25nov();
            obj.maxNumberIs(54,4);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer doesn't explain anything to the OP thus isn't helpful.

Comment: @Troubleshoot we are also allowed to provide an alternate solution,+1 from my side

Comment: @JqueryLearner The OP would actually learn something if an explanation was provided. Just providing correct code for what looks like homework is not helpful.

Comment: @Troubleshoot Yes I agree with you.But before downvoting we should suggest the answerer first.Also the answerer is new so we should help them how to answer in a best way